# How to remove the focus box on the url bar in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Since my last question regarding getting rid of chrome's annoyances got moved here I'm just asking this one here. There's a blue outline around the url bar in chrome. How do I get rid of it?

[image: blue outline]

Comment: It is only there if you click on or very near the URL. Click somewhere else and the blue highlight disappears. I am sure some people find that helps them focus themselves on the URL.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not using a dark theme. Incognito mode is just like that.

Answer (score 1):

The blue box around the URL is not a function of, or unique to Chrome.

The blue box appears in Google Chrome and also in Chromium Edge. Same thing.

So blue box is part of the common foundation to the two browsers and there is no setting to remove it in either browser.

Click somewhere else and the blue highlight disappears. I am sure some people find that helps them focus themselves on the URL.

Followup: The same thing occurs from time to time in Firefox. So it is a very common user feature.

I suggest just adapting to it. I hardly even notice it.

Comment: Are there any flags to disable it? Or extensions that allow customizing chrome? Clicking somewhere else isn't the answer. It doesn't disable the highlight from appearing unless I never use the address bar, which isn't an option since it's necessary to get to websites. It's a so-called "feature" that got changed in the latest update to be even more annoying. You may not notice it but I find it incredibly intrusive and distracting so I just want it gone.

Comment: The blue bar (bars evident in Google Chrome, Chromium Edge and Firefox) is built right into the main program. So there is no way I know to turn it off. You would need to enter a feature request to the browser companies.